# Get Order by increment_id

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order, csv, increment-id

I'm trying to read from a csv file a list of `increment_ids` and get order using them.

```
if (($file = fopen('increment_ids.csv','r')) != FALSE) {
    while($data = fgetcsv($file,0,"\t")) {
        $incremenet_id = $data[0];
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incremenet_id);
        print_r($order);
        break;
    ...
```

The issue is that when `print_r($order)` is empty but when use a number instead of the variable, the variable `$order` has the informations. I can echo `$data[0]` without a problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check the answers and give some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code..

```
$file = 'increment_ids.csv';
$headers = false;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if (empty($handle) === false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($headers) {
            $incremenet_id = $data[0];
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incremenet_id);
            print_r($order->getData());
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: No it does not work. When i do echo $data[0] : it displays 21452 but loadByIncrementId($data[0]) returns empty $order by using directly the number 21452 gives order information.
I have order like 21456-3 in my file and they displayed with out problem upon reading from the file.

Comment: are you  sure  $data[0]  contained the increment id. Can you please do echo $data[0]  and confirm.

Comment: I'm 100% positive. 
`12000|| 
000013561-1||210.0000
`
Here a caption, i have result from the second and not from the first althought there are both orders. Increment_id || $order->getGrandTotal();

Comment: then nothing wrong with that, you can try some different way.

Answer (score 0):

This should work too (should be better then `loadByIncrementId()` in a loop)

```
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setDelimiter("\t");
$file = 'increment_ids.csv';
$data = $csv->getData($file);

$columnNumber = 0; # depends on your csv structure
$incrementIds = array_column($data, $columnNumber);

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', $incrementIds);

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    var_dump($order->getData());
}
```

Comment: My file is tab-separated. when i echo $incrementsIds it's empty.

Comment: @mockingbid added `setDelimiter("\t")` to work with tabs. Depending on your CSV you have to adjust the `$columnNumber` var